# Usar la validación solamente de un atributo de mi clase, sin formularios

Tags: java, validación, spring-boot, thymeleaf

quisiera saber si puedo validar solamente un **atributo** de una **clase** sin necesidad de enviar todo el **objeto** por un **formulario** (con metodo post y esas cosas), es decir, con solo enviar el atributo (a la función de mi controlador) que quiero validar pueda usar la validación que esta especificada en mi clase.

Aquí un breve resumen de mi código...

1. En mi clase tengo el atributo que quiero validar `dni`:

   ```
   @NotEmpty
   @Size(min=8, max=8, message="Debe tener 8 numeros")
   // Más validaciones
   private String dni;

   /* Más atributos */
   ```
2. En mi controlador tengo la siguiente función que recibe el atributo `dni` mediante ajax con jquery

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value="/buscarPersona")
   public String buscarPersona(@RequestParam("dni") Long dni, Model model){

       /* procedimiento */
   }
   ```
3. En mi vista tengo el siguiente input que quiero validar, donde el botón, al ser clickeado llama a una función jquery para enviar el valor del input a la función del controlador

   ```
   <div th:object="${persona}" >
       <label> DNI: </label>
       <input type="text" th:field="*{dni}" class="form-control" th:errorclass="'form-control alert-danger'" />
       <small class="form-text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('dni')}" th:errors="*{dni}"></small>
       <button id="buscarPersona" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Si lo que quieres es validar sin pasar por el backend, **nunca hagas eso**. Desde que el cliente escribe sus datos hasta que llegan a tu servidor pueden pasar muchas cosas.

Comment: Si solo quieres validar que tenga 8 caracteres te recomiendo que lo hagas con JavaScript (JQuery por ejemplo). Te vas a evitar muchos problemas. Después con `@Valid` compruebas que todo tu objeto esté correcto.

Comment: @David DPG, por eso está publicación, quiero pasar por el backend utilizando las validaciones de sus clases...

Comment: @Angel, tienes razón pero quiero ir por el backend también... Me olvide colocar que son más validaciones, ya lo corregí.

Comment: @LuiggiCarreraMuñoz Hasta donde tengo entendido no. Se me ocurre que hagas una clase con un solo parámetro.